# Permanently removing effective permissions in MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

So I was toying around with permissions/roles/etc.
I added a windows user, I gave him sysadmin role, then I took away sysadmin role from this user.

There are no user mapping whatsoever.
I explicitly denied all the securables, yet in

Login Properties -> Securables -> permissions -> effective
There are still all the permissions on the list.

What am I doing wrong, and how to fix this?

Comment: You cannot "drop" `sysadmin` role. Please clarify your question.

Comment: You're right! I meant that I took away this role from the user, I edited my original question.

Comment: Do a select from sys.login_token and sys.user_token while impersonating the user to see what they're a member of at the server and database level.